# class in echo not working

Tags: php, class, echo

Ok, I know this has been asked a number of times but I could not find a solution.

```
<?php echo '<span class="teamname">' . the_field('team_1') . '</span>'; ?>
```

The class does not work and the field does not display inside the span.

Can someone help?

Comment: The php tags are there, this forms part of a bigger piece of code already wrapped in php tags

Comment: Is this maybe a method from custom fields wordpress plugin?

Comment: @Phil Yes it is, I'm using ACF and busy placing the custom fields in a custom loop for the archive.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Have you checked the generated parsed HTML and verified that it does not have the class? Or is it just the styles for `.teamname` is not defined and therefore you are not seeing the effect applying to your span element?

Comment: Crap! I'm sorry, my first time here asking for help, I should have been more specific.

The class is there, just so I can style the span, but what is not working is the field is not displaying inside the span, that's my main problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_field('YOURFIELD')` instead of `the_field('YOURFIELD')`.

```
<?php 
    echo '<span class="teamname">' . get_field('team_1') . '</span>';
?>
```

Docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to echo the return value of the_field() function. The correct use of this function is:

```
<span class="teamname"><?php the_field('team_1'); ?></span>
```